# Flutter slider with web

Tags: flutter-web

I am trying to build music player app which has slider, my current slider code shown below works fine with Mobile device but it doesn't work on Flutter web, it seems like flutter slider doesn't support slider on web yet. I tried finding out alternative packages but none of them seems to support web. Is there any customized version which we can use for web?

```
Widget slider() {
    return Slider(
        activeColor: Colors.white10,
        inactiveColor: AppColors.red200,
        label: inuseAudioinfo.duration.inSeconds.toString(),
        min: 0.0,
        max: (inuseAudioinfo.position.inSeconds ?? 0.0).toDouble(),
        value: (getSleepkerPosition(inuseAudioinfo.position.inSeconds,
                inuseAudioinfo.duration.inSeconds))
            .toDouble(),
        divisions: 9,
        onChangeStart: (double value) {
          print('Start value is ' + value.toString());
        },
        onChangeEnd: (double value) {
          print('Finish value is ' + value.toString());
        },
        onChanged: (double value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value == inuseAudioinfo.position.inSeconds) {
            } else {
              seekToSecond(value.toInt());
              value = value;
            }
          });
        });
  }
```

Comment: The Slider widget is supported on web. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, i can see widget there but it doesn't move when music is playing. It works fine in mobile, i saw somewhere in Slider doc that it doesn't support web yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers` plugin to get position and duration, it seems like this plugin doesn't support web yet. I replaced my code with `https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player` and it worked.